# Which device will allow me to simply capture 24v?

Tags: component-selection, 24v, pc

I'm new to electronics, struggling to work out whether this is simple and I'm missing something or whether it's a lot more complicated that what I anticipated.

I have something (some device) that is currently outputting a 24v pulse. Via USB (so that I can listen on a serial connection in code), I want to receive that 24v signal on my PC.

So, device outputting 24v outputs it through wires to a device (the device I need) which then (via USB) tells my PC it's received a signal which I can poll from code.

### What I've Tried

Not sure if it's something like this that I need?

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/8-CH-24V-Computer-PC-Intelligent-USB-Control-Switch-Drive-free-Relay-Switch-/232737498890

or in fact something simpler, like this....

https://www.amazon.co.uk/TOPINCN-Intelligent-Protection-Converter-Regulator/dp/B07MZ67FZR

Comment: You can use a very simple circuit called a *resistor divider* to reduce your 24 V pulse to 5 V or 3.3 V, then use a "GPIO" module to receive the pulse and communicate with the PC over USB.

Answer (score 1):

1. Buy a USB GPIO expander
2. Try the FTDI chip driver IC. It converts PC USB into UART plus Frome GPIOs which you can use
3. Buy an Arduino and interface 24 V suitably to it. Send UART messages to PC from there

You have to condition the pulse. May I know the pulse details? Frequency and pulse width

Answer (score 0):

There are two challenges here. First, most devices cannot take in a 24V input (unless you are willing to spend some extra money) and second you do not want to have to deal with USB communications.

Therefore it would be best to feed your 24V into some sort of microcontroller such as an arduino or a raspberry pi that could be connected to a computer via USB. Of course, these devices cannot handle 24V so you need to step it down to something more manageable like 2V. You could use a DC buck converter or as someone else suggested create your own circuit with a voltage divider. I do not know how your are interfacing the 24V pulse but either should be fine.